# Cannot read property 'define' of undefined ( sequelize defining model)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I'm using node.js version 10.13.0, with SEQUELIZE version 4.42.0, and I try to define a set of models, but i have a problem in the date.js file, it says :

> Cannot read property 'define' of undefined
>   it happens when i run a test with connect.js file.
>   this is the structure of the project :

[image: project structure image 1]
[image: project structure image 2]

so i do the following in date.js

```
function init(){
console.log(sequelize);
const Date = sequelize.define('date' , {
    id : {
        type : sequelize.DataTypes.BIGINT(5),
        allowNull : false,
        autoIncrement : true,
        primaryKey : true
    },
    starting_date : {
        type : sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull : true,
        defaultValue : null
    },
    ending_date : {
        type : sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull : true,
        defaultValue: null
    },
    now : {
        type : sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull : true,
        defaultValue : true
    }
});

Date.associate = function(models){
    Date.belongsToMany(models.email , {through : models.task});
    Date.belongsToMany(models.user , {through : models.task});
};

return Date;
}
module.exports = init();
```

and this the connect.js script :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = 'development';
const config = require('../config/config')[env];

const sequelize  = new Sequelize(config.database.database_name, 
config.database.username, config.database.password, 
config.database.database_config);

var db = {
    sequelize : sequelize,
    Sequelize : Sequelize
};

fs.readdirSync("./models/").filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && 
(file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join("./models", file));
    db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
       db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
 });

 db.authenticate().then(() => {
console.log('database worked !!!');
}).catch(error => {
   console.log(error.stack);
});


module.exports = db;
```

the whole project is in this link: https://github.com/ekkatharisi/mailer

as final result, I want to build this database as described in scheme :
[image: class diagram scheme]

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read your errormessage carefully. It states that you cannot read "define" from "undefined".

The only place you are reading "define" is at the start of your date.js where you `sequelize.define(...`.

So you are reading "define" from undefined means, that "sequelize" is undefined. And this is may be true, because you are not importing any library there. And if you are importing something, your import is wrong. Otherwise "sequelize" would not be "undefined" and so that errormessage would not show up.

Comment: thank you @spyro for the quick reply , and yes i understand the errormessage but that not mean that sequelize is not imported becaus sequelize is impored the last version locally and globaly , see the package.json in githup project

Comment: another thing, when I show sequelize object with console.log() in connect.js it's not undefined !!! what is the problem?